# Enumerate with in a custom environment breaks

Tags: environments, enumerate

I'm trying to write a custom environment, but I keep running into a strange error..

This is my setup

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{advdate}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\environbodyname\scenarioBODY
\NewEnviron{scenario}
{
  \renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0.8ex}
    \setlength\LTleft{0pt}
    \setlength\LTright{0pt}
    \longtable{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll@{}}
    \hline
    {\bf Scenario name} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Some scenario} \\
    \hline
    \endhead 

    body & \scenarioBODY \\

    {\bf Total} & {\bf 100 DKK} \\
    \hline
    \endlongtable
}
```

It works with

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{scenario}
        Some body
    \end{scenario}
\end{document}
```

but not with

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{scenario}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Some body
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{scenario}
\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `\longtable{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lp{3cm}@{}}` rather then `\longtable{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll@{}}`

Comment: Thanks; that worked. But why?

Comment: Don't use `l` column type to insert paragraph or list, instead you can use `p{<width>}` [tables-wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables)

Comment: @cholewa1992 - Use `\bseries` intead of `\bf`, those old commands will cause errors, depending of the documentclass. Read the manual of the array package to learn about different kinds of columns (`texdoc array`) on the command line. The l-type throws an error, if there is a `\par` in the content, the p-type not. The enumerate env. and such end an item with a paragraph.

Comment: Thanks @KeksDose. I managed to solve the problem; it was as you say due to the use of l-type instead of p-types. But also the latex compiler made i really hard to figure out that that was the error ;-)

Comment: @SalimBou; if you add you comment as an answer I can mark it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments: You can't insert paragraphs or lists in `l` columns.  Use a `p` column instead, e.g.

```
\longtable{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lp{3cm}@{}}
```